# Check the existance of an NSURL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession

I want to check if a file exists on my server through NSURL and thanks to NSURLSession (maybe not the best solution ?). To do this, I performed these couple of lines:

Method used in ViewControllerB:

```
- (void)testFichierExiste:(void(^)(int intTest))retourErreur atURL:(NSURL *)cheminTest {

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:cheminTest];
request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
    if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 403) { //file exists
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            retourErreur(1); //Send "1" to my ViewControllerA to say file exists
        });
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Method called from ViewControllerA:

```
__block int fileExist = 0;
[[[ViewControllerB alloc] init] testFichierExiste:^(int retourSession) {
    fileExist = retourSession; //doesn't work
} atURL:nbComptes]; //nbComptes = same path as cheminTest in ViewControllerB
```

On my ViewControllerA, I have the result "1" when the file exists, and "nil" when it is the contrary with the value of `retourSession`.
But to release of the block `testFichierExiste:^(int retourSession)`, I need to affect the value of `retourSession` to another int variable `fileExist`.
But this transfer of value doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
2018-04-18 18:34:28.978024+0200 AppTest[3284:76369] fileExist value: 0
2018-04-18 18:34:29.142198+0200 AppTest[3284:76369] retourSession value: 1
```

I was thinking maybe at a problem because of different class between the two variables ?
Regards.

Comment: Can you let us know where are you testing the value of fileExist? Most likely the callback (retourSession) still hasn't executed and you're simply printing the initial value.

Comment: I agree with @pfandrade's suggestion. I'd also advise setting a breakpoint on retourError(1); in the first code snippet, and stepping into the retourError block. Could be something like the dataTaskWithRequest: callback block not being called.

Comment: I agree with my two predecessors on the async issue. Also, when it's fixed, you might want to execute the completion block (`retourSession()`) in the `else` test of your `if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 403)`.

Comment: Could be a sandboxing issue. You might not have the entitlement set to make outgoing network connections. Try turning App Sandbox off.

Comment: @pfandrade I'm testing the value of fileExist in the ViewControllerB. But you're all right, I figure out it's an async issue... But how can I fix it ? Because I added the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ })` especially to avoid this async issue, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the information of whether or not the file exists you'll need to wait for the request to finish and the callback has executed.

I guess what your trying to do is update the `fileExist` var and update some UI depending on its value.

```
__block int fileExist = 0;
[[[ViewControllerB alloc] init] testFichierExiste:^(int retourSession) {
    fileExist = retourSession; //doesn't work
} atURL:nbComptes]; //nbComptes = same path as cheminTest in ViewControllerB

// you probably have some code here testing fileExist
```

This won't work because you never waited for the callback. Perhaps you can solve your issue by having a method on your view controller that will update the UI based on that callback result.

```
ViewControllerB *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[vcB testFichierExiste:^(int retourSession) {
    [vcB updateUIForExistenceOfFile:retourSession]; 
} atURL:nbComptes];

- (void)updateUIForExistenceOfFile:(int)fileExist {
    // update your UI
}
```

Comment: Exactly ! (sorry for my lack of clearness), my code just after depends on the value of `retourSession`. Your solution will work, but I need to check in my application more than 300 times if a file exists or not, so that means I will need to create a new method at each time with your solution.. (therefore I call the test method in another file instead of use it in each file). I don't know if you understand what I mean.